# Can't preview a shapefile in GeoServer 2.2.4

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I have problem with previewing layers in GeoServer. I installed Geoserver 2.2.4 (following instructions in manual) and everything was going well. I managed to login to it and create my own new workspace. I've created a new store and published that layer but when I try to preview that layer with openLayers all I see is empty map with no features on it. I've also tried with example on http://docs.geoserver.org/2.2.4/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/index.html  to see if the problem is with my shapefile but the same thing happens. I really don't know why because all I did was the same as it is written in manual. I hope somebody can help me with that. Thanks

Comment: What about previewing in another format?  Do you get output using GML or GeoJSON for example?

Comment: No , same thing for all formats. But I found the problem. I will post it here as an answer now so other people could see it if they come to the same problem

Comment: hi i tried also JRE6 environment and it didnt change anything again. Only 2.2 on my old xp computer is working. Please let me know which version is ok for set up geoserver on windows 7 ultimate?

Comment: Hi, at the end I've installed Geoserver as a WAR in Apache Tomcat and I use windows 7 too.
Maybe it's a little bit harder to configure it to work with apache but it's still easy and it could be very helpful later in your work. You can check this site http://gbif.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-configure-geoserver.html to help you configure it. 
I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem now.
The problem was obviously in the version of java runtime environment that I had installed. First I installed jre7 but now I uninstalled it and installed jre6 instead and now it works perfectly. I really can't understand what's the problem with jre7 but it looks like this is the only way to fix this problem.